# Search for a word in whole word document without opening it

Tags: c#, winforms, office-interop

I want searching for a word in whole word document without opening it.

I search in every site and read all Questions here but there is an error when using this code (Using a `Range Object`)

```
object findText = "find me";

Word.Range rng = this.Paragraphs[2].Range; 

rng.Find.ClearFormatting();

if (rng.Find.Execute(ref findText,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, 
    ref missing, ref missing)) 
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("Text found.");
} 
else 
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("Text not found.");
} 

rng.Select();
```

But I have an error in

```
Paragraphs[2]
```

when open big file. The error is:

> ref missing

Comment: No. of Paragraphs bigger than 2 so its give me error can't reach it -----          Second error in (( missing )) can't found it

Comment: Are you aware that C# uses 0-indexed arrays? if you have 2 paragraphs then you will want `Paragraphs[1]`

Comment: But i don't  know the numbers of Paragraphs in the word file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should count the paragraphs numbers in whole document using

```
int docc = wordfile.Paragraphs.Count;
```

So when you open big files, it will count all paragraphs in the file.
Then using (( docc )) in the range code

```
Range rng = wordfile.Paragraphs[docc].Range;
```

Second error you can use (( Type.Missing )) instead of (( ref missing ))

so the code will be

```
object findText = "find me";
int docc = wordfile.Paragraphs.Count;
Range rng = wordfile.Paragraphs[docc].Range;
rng.Find.ClearFormatting();

if (rng.Find.Execute(ref findText,
Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,Type.Missing,
Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
Type.Missing, Type.Missing)) 
 { 
  MessageBox.Show("Text found.");
 } 
else 
{ 
 MessageBox.Show("Text not found.");
} 

rng.Select();
```

Comment: wow , Working like a charm with me                                                                      Thanks, You saved my time.

Comment: No, It will count Paragraphs number and back with its numbers ( 0 or 1 or 2 or ....... ) @Sayse